# JSON - Create JSONObject with array

Tags: java, android, json

I need to create in a Java (Android) a JSONObject/JSONArray with the exact following structure:

```
{
    "listId": 
    [
        "c02bc683-fcd7-47a5-b157-853e26ed099e",
        "f8e1c9d7-ae45-4433-a315-726c1d912d09"
    ]
}
```

Can somebody help me on this please?

EDIT:

What i have is this:

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

jsonObject.put("listId", folderId);
obj.put(jsonObject);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("id", obj);
```

But this produces something like:

```
{
    "listId": 
    [
        {"id":"c02bc683-fcd7-47a5-b157-853e26ed099e"},
        {"id":"f8e1c9d7-ae45-4433-a315-726c1d912d09"}
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your array creation a bit mixed up.  What you really want is an object holding an array of string, but what you're doing is creating an array of `JSONObject`.

Try this instead:

```
    String[] arr = { "c02bc683-fcd7-47a5-b157-853e26ed099e", "f8e1c9d7-ae45-4433-a315-726c1d912d09" };
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arr);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("listId", jsonArray);

    System.out.println(json); // {"listId":["c02bc683-fcd7-47a5-b157-853e26ed099e","f8e1c9d7-ae45-4433-a315-726c1d912d09"]}
```